# Diagnose encryption problem in Microsoft Outlook?

Tags: encryption, windows-8, microsoft-outlook

I am unable to send an encrypted email to a party for whom I have a certificate. How can I diagnose the problem? Microsoft's error message does not explain what the problem is:

[image]

Notes:

- The party's certificate is valid and up to date and associated with their contact
- I have verified that the recipient's certificate is present both in the Windows certificate store, and in the certificate list in Outlook
- I have mailed directly TO... the contact with the certificate
- The certificate listed in both the contact list and in the Windows certificate store is the only one, and it is valid and up to date
- I have restarted the machine cold and restarted Microsoft Outlook
- I have emptied the autocomplete list
- Machine is runing Windows 8.1 Enterprise
- Outlook is version 2013

Comment: You should first try to contact Microsft Outlook support.

Comment: What version of Outlook are you using?